# How to come parent viewcontroller from child viewcontroller by using scrolling action?

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, poptoviewcontroller

I have two UIViewController named as `ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB`. ViewControllerA is the parent class and ViewControllerB is a child class, it is view by `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];` from ViewControllerA class. In ViewControllerB class i hidden the NavigationBar. In button action i coded to come ViewControllerA from ViewControllerB `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. Now, i want to come ViewControllerA from ViewControllerB using swapping action(Scroll to previous screen) rather than using UIButton. How can i do this? Can anyone please provide me any suggestion or ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in child controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{    
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer  *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release]; 
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
 {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Swipe received.");
 }
```

Use Direction as you want..

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on your child view with handler method that does the `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.